# How can I get easily started with discord_slash python module?

Tags: python, discord.py

**discord_slash** is for anyone who is new to discord_slash pretty complicated and in my opinion the docs are a bit weird and hard to understand, so here is a beginner guide to get started with the third-party discord.py extension.

***To understand this completely you also have to have at least a bit experience in discord.py and experience in python!***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## !! This documentation summary is outdated but mostly still works

### Installing the module

To install the module, just enter this in your Python "Script" Folder CMD (Python Folder > Scripts, then type at the top where your path is "cmd"):

```
pip install discord-py-slash-command
```

After that don't forget to add your bot with the **additional scope** *applications.commands* (`scope=bot%20applications.commands`). You can get a link or other scopes like shown on the picture of the [Discord Dev Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
[image: Discord Dev Image]

### [Official Documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

### Simpliest code

To get started, we will firstly create the **simpliest code** to get our first slash command to discord:

```py
import discord                     # Import the original discord.py module
from discord.ext import commands   # Import the discord.py extension "commands"
import discord_slash               # Import the third-party extension discord_slash module


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')   # Define your bot variable you will also use for defining the slash 
                                         # command variable
slash = discord_slash.SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)      # sync_commands is for doing synchronization for 
                                                                 # every command you add, remove or update in your
                                                                 # code
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")    # Making sure our bot runs

###################################################################################################################

@slash.slash(name="test", description="Those burgers look tasty",        # Adding a new slash command with our slash variable
             options=[discord_slash.manage_commands.create_option(name="first_option", description="Please enter what you want on your burger", option_type=3, required=False)])
async def test(ctx: discord_slash.SlashContext, first_option):               # You have to name the function the 
    await ctx.send(f'I am now gonna get you a burger with {first_option}')   # same as the command

###################################################################################################################

bot.run('TOKEN')   # for TOKEN insert your token, if you have any questions regarding this do not leave your token 
                   # there!!
```

### Explanation of the slash command adding

This will now create a **new slash command** with the name "test", the description as it is above and an optional option called "first_option" which you also have to have as parameter in your function.

The **option type 3** means the user can only input a **string**.

Which other types there are is shown a bit lower also what is what when your command shows up in discord.

This command is now **global**, so it can be called everywhere in Discord where your bot is! If you want it guild-specific, add `guild_ids=GUILD_IDS` to `@slash.slash()` with GUILD_IDS as list of all server IDs you want this command in to the option.

Also be **careful** with [`ctx`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord_slash.context.html#discord_slash.context.SlashContext) as it got new functions and not everything is supported. Things like [`ctx.channel.send`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-ctx-send-and-ctx-channel-send) could fail as the channel could not be defined. `ctx.send` will send a direct response to the command.

You can also add **custom choices** by adding

```
choices=[discord_slash.utils.manage_commands.create_option(name: str, description: str, option_type: Union[int, type], required: bool, choices: Optional[list])]
```

to the option.

### Manually deleting commands

So let's firstly get to how you **manually delete** slash commands; You can do this with:

```
await discord_slash.utils.manage_commands.remove_all_commands(bot_id, bot_token, guild_ids: Optional[List of integers])
```

For **removing specific commands** you need the **command ID** to do;

```
await discord_slash.utils.manage_commands.remove_slash_command(bot_id, bot_token, guild_id, command_id)
```

If I am right you can **get the command ID** with

```
await discord_slash.utils.manage_commands.get_all_commands(bot_id, bot_token, guild_id)
```

### Option Types

The option types are as following:

| Type | Integer |
| --- | --- |
| SUB_COMMAND | 1 |
| SUB_COMMAND_GROUP | 2 |
| STRING | 3 |
| INTEGER | 4 |
| BOOLEAN | 5 |
| USER | 6 |
| CHANNEL | 7 |
| ROLE | 8 |

For **User, Channel and Role** the user will have the option to choose directly the specific thing with the menu like you would **mention** it, also this will be passed directly as **the class** it was entered so not as ID or else.

### How the command is shown

Here are 2 images how it will look in Discord when you type "/":

(I am using a BetterDiscord Theme so don't wonder why it looks "weird")

**Normal Command**:

[image: Command in Discord]

| Colour | What it is | What it is for the example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Name of the command, has to be a string with 1-32 characters | "test" |
| Green | Parameters the user has to enter | "first_option" |
| Blue | Means the following parameters are optional | Everything after it so "first_option" in this case as we entered `required=False` |
| Yellow | The description of the command, has to be a string with 1-100 characters | "Those burgers look tasty" |

**Specifically the option**:

[image: Option Picture]

| Colour | What it is | What it is for the example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green | The parameters ("name" is red because I entered no or a false value) | "first_option", in the example case you can only enter a string for this (`option_type=3`) |
| Red | I selected the optional parameter "userbegrenzung" to enter a value for this and see the description | Marked red just for showing |
| Yellow | The option description | "Please take down what you want on your burger" |

---

**I hope you now understand the module a bit better! If you have any questions or suggestions regarding this feel free to write a comment!**

Comment: It's worth mentioning that from discord.py 2.0 slash commands will be supported natively, so using this library will not be necessary.

Comment: But as this probably needs some time and the slash command feature is pretty cool, everyone who wants it needs to get in it which is in my opinion a bit hard with the original docs