# Discord module not found? Slash command

Tags: python, discord

from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'

here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@slash.slash(
    name='embed',
    description='Send an example embed message'
)
async def embed(ctx: SlashContext, accent_color: str = None):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.send('Only administrators can use this command.')
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Example Embed',
        description='This is an example of an embed message',
        color=discord.Color.blue() if accent_color is None else discord.Color(int(accent_color, 16))
    )

    embed.set_author(
        name=ctx.author.name,
        icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url
    )

    embed.add_field(name='Field 1', value='Value 1', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Field 2', value='Value 2', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Field 3', value='Value 3', inline=False)

    embed.set_footer(
        text='Accent color',
        icon_url='https://www.example.com/accent_icon.png'
    )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@slash.slash(
    name='setstatus',
    description='Set the bot status',
    options=[
        {
            'name': 'status',
            'description': 'The new status message',
            'type': 3,  # String type
            'required': True
        }
    ]
)
async def setstatus(ctx: SlashContext, status: str):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.send('Only administrators can use this command.')
        return

    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=status))
    await ctx.send(f'Bot status updated to: {status}')
bot.run('token')
```

I tried install interaction module, py slash commands and etc still no luck and requirements txt is there so like wth get this try usinmg different library    from discord_interactions import CommandContext, OptionType, Option
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_interactions'

Comment: How did you install the 'py slash' command?   Might https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502375/how-can-i-get-easily-started-with-discord-slash-python-module help?

Comment: _ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_interactions'_ According to the [documentation](https://github.com/interactions-py/interactions.py), the module name is just `interactions`.  Why are you using `discord_interactions`?